# Android, how to make widget fit screen width

Tags: android, widget

In my Android application I tried creating a widget which has to fit the width of the screen like this

[image]

to do that I tried creating multi dimens for different resolutions

dimens sw340
dimens sw600
dimens sw720
dimens sw820

but I still get wrong in some devices.

What is the standard way to solve this problem?